# Load different options depending on package version

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, package-options, obsolete

Is there any possibility to load a package with different options depending on the version of the package?

The command

```
\@ifpackagelater{package}{date}{true}{false}
```

only works if the package is already loaded and the options cannot be changed anymore.

To be precise, I want to load the `biblatex` package with different options depending on its version, since some options are not available in former versions.

Answer (score 10):

While I don't know how to conditionally invoke package options at load time, in the case of `biblatex` most options (except style specifications, compatibility options and choosing the backend) can also bet set afterwards using `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`. For example, the `url` option (which was introduced in `biblatex` v0.9) could be conditionally disabled using

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{biblatex}{2010/02/14}{\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{url=false}}{}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't clear. If you're the author of the document, you know the options that shipped with the latest version of the package. They're in the package documentation (and in the source or `.sty` file, if you can read them).

The `biblatex` package has load-time and preamble options. For load-time options, it is advisable to call the latest options that you need and are available at the time you're loading the package. You can use the optional version argument (eg, [2011/07/29] below) to insist on the version (or a newer one) of the package you need.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp]{biblatex}[2011/07/29]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
```

lockstep has indicated how preamble options may be invoked.